# Getting Pure CSS Menu inside Div Region?

Tags: html, css

I'm using the Pure CSS menu from here:

```
http://csswizardry.com/2011/02/creating-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu/
```

It works fine, but I now want to put this menu inside another div region. But it will only appear below it. I can make it appear inside by setting overflow to auto, but then the menu's do not expand on mouse over. Here is what it looks like:

```
http://chemsworks.com/so/index.html
```

I just want the menu bar inside the blue section?

I haven't posted my CSS or HTML because you'll be able to get that from the linked page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix your menu remove that bar (|) character you have after your navbar div, before your menu, and properly clear your menu, like so:

```
.navbar:before, .navbar:after {
    display: table;
    content: "";
    zoom:1; /* fix for IE */
}

.navbar:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add `display:inline` for `#nav` or remove `float:left` from `#nav li` and add `display:inline-block`. I don't know which one you try to achieve, but both will show the menu inside blue but different.